# Deployed all the files in Azure correctly but still not able to see webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, deployment, azure-devops

I am trying to deploy Asp .Net5 webapp in Azure. I have created the pipelines and successfully deployed the same. But the issue I am facing this when I am trying to visit my website, It's showing

> Your app service is up and running. Time to take the next step and
> deploy your code.

I am already deployed my code. So it can't be deployment issue. My guess is It must be some runtime issue but the problem is How can I debug without any Error or something.

I can see my files in Kudu console.
[image: Here we can see the files]

Pipelines and Releases in *dev.azure.com* are showing correct too.
[image]

My yml file

```
# ASP.NET Core (.NET Framework)
# Build and test ASP.NET Core projects targeting the full .NET Framework.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/dotnet-core

trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
    - master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- checkout: self
  submodules: true

- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:EnvironmentName=$(EnvironmentName) /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    pathToPublish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
    artifactName: MFLBuildOutput
```

Please help me. Any kind of help will be highly appreciated.

**EDIT**:

For deploy, I already have created a release pipeline which looks like this-
[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to the steps you have shared I couldn't find the task that deploys the app. Your pipeline only generating the artifacts but not deploying to azure. Please add the deploy step,

[image]

You can find the same here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app-deployment?view=azure-devops

Comment: Do I still need to mention this job in yml file if I deployed manually? And also in Kudu console, I can see all the files so I guess this is not a problem. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: For deployement, I have created the release pipeline (I have added the screenshot above). The yml file for release looks like the one you wrote here.

Comment: Can you show the screenshot of the build artifact linked to the release pipeline?

Comment: Yes, I have added screenshot above. (after EDIT)